# How do I change permissions of a file on SDCard?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, partitions

I am making an image file of the partitions on my phone's internal memory. The images are being stored on the phone's SD card (for obvious reasons, I can't store them on interal memory).

I'll need to view these files in Windows later. However, dd is creating them so only root can see them.

Apparently, changing permissions of files on the external SDCard is difficult, but I need to do it.

Alternatively, how do I make dd create the file with the right permissions in the first place?

Comment: [partition backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ma.wanam.partitions) is an app - as an alternative

Comment: Good suggestion, but I've already polluted the phone with loads of SMS recovery tools which didn't work and may have overwritten the data I need. Would like to avoid installing yet another utility if I can avoid it.

Comment: That's fine, was pointing to an alternative :)